# Call ES6 functions from es5

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, function-call

I'm trying to "combine" ES6 with ES5. I'm want to program in ES6 so I'm using a transpiler, but I also want to call an "initialization" function from normal ES5 code so it then calls all ES6 transpiled stuff. How can I do that?

Edit:

The code I'm trying to call (just testing):

```
export function someFunction() {
  console.log('hi')
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code you are trying to call.

Comment: Please expand on _"I also want to call an "initialization" function from normal ES5 code so it then calls all ES6 transpiled stuff"_ as it's not clear what you mean...

Comment: Is your question about importing ES6 modules in ES5, or really about function calls?

Comment: @Bergi function calls, I don't need to import the whole module. The process I want to achieve is: request a page via HTTP, this page contains a call to a function, this function is the interface to the weirdly transpiled code.

Comment: @sdgluck The process I want to achieve is: request a page via HTTP, this page contains a call to a function, this function is the interface to the weirdly transpiled code.

Comment: @vicaba "interface to the weirdly transpiled code" is exactly what an import is? Your problem seems to be getting a reference to the exported function, as calling it just works as with every function.

Comment: @Bergi but I can't use the "import" statement in ES5. Also, if you mean using the <script> tag, I don't really want this, I've already done this with the whole transpiled bundle, I want to expose several functions to the ES5 code from the bundle.

Comment: An `import` statement is only one way to import modules. What you likely want is to make several of the exports globally available (possibly namespaced). Look into the options of your bundler, it let's you do these things. If you need further help, please show us your bundler/transpilation settings and how you attempted to invoke the function.